# Is any ring map between two $K$- extensions necessarily $K$-linear?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

This may sound really obvious but I was considering the following:

Suppose $K$ is a field and $M,L$ are two extensions of $K$ (often denoted by $M|K, L|K$). If I consider a ring homomorphism from $M$ to $L$, say $\phi:M\to L$. Is it necessarily true that $\phi$ is $K$-linear? That is, is it necessarily true that $\phi(km)=k\phi(m) \forall k\in K,m\in M$?

Comment: This cannot be true when $K=M=L$ and $\phi:K\to K$ is any ring homomorphism other than $k\mapsto \lambda k$, e.g. $K=M=L=\mathbb{C}$ and $z\mapsto\overline{z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not. Take, for instance, $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt2)$ and (as a trivial example) $M=L=K$. Now there is a ring homomorphism $M\longrightarrow L$ with $a+b\sqrt2\mapsto a-b\sqrt2$. This homomorphism doesn't satisfy $\phi(k)=k$ for all $k\in K$, so it's not $K$-linear.

But even if you want less trivial examples, take $K$ as above and $M=\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3),~L=\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\sqrt5)$. Then we have a homomorphism $\phi:M\longrightarrow L$ given by
$$a+b\sqrt2+c\sqrt3+d\sqrt6\mapsto a-b\sqrt2+c\sqrt3-d\sqrt6.$$
This is also not $K$-linear.

The fact that $K$-linearity isn't guaranteed is, by the way, the reason why we explicitly define the Galois group of a Galois extension as $\operatorname{Gal}(M\vert K):=\operatorname{Aut}_K(L)$, that is, the automorphisms $L\longrightarrow L$ which fix $K$ elementwise. In other words, the $K$-linear automorphisms of $L$.